# How do I make HP Universal Print Driver the default driver for certain printers

Tags: windows-7, drivers, printer

HP does not release individual drivers for certain printer models anymore. When Windows 7 goes to search for the driver(windows update), it does not find drivers. I have the HP Universal Print Driver installed on the PC already but I have to browse and choose it when I plug the printer in for the first time. How do I make the printers automatically choose HP UPD. Is there a tool? I've used the HP Driver Deployment tool but not exactly what I need. TIA.

Comment: Have a look at [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2500967), see if it'll solve the problem.

Comment: But I want to it to install drivers. I want to automatically install HP Universal Print Driver for that printer. I need a way to associate HP Universal Print Driver to the printers I plug in(without doing it manually to each one).